# How to do Product wise shipping method Selection in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.5

Hello I have 3 products in my cart , now i want to select product wise shipping method means in my cart there is 2 product is only for store pickup and 1 product is available for home delivery i want to make Shipping method select on product level , there is extension or any solution available?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this extension:
https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-shipping-per-product.html
https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/shipping-per-product-destination-wise
https://store.webkul.com/magento2-multi-vendor-per-product-shipping.html

Might help you.
Happy coding.

Comment: This Extension is apply for the whole cart in magento2 , i want shipping method selection product wise .